# git-tfs and msysgit on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, git, msysgit

I've installed msysgit [`msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.4-preview20110204.exe`] on Windows 7 64-bit, and extracted git-tfs [`GitTfs-0.11.0.zip`] into a directory on my machine.

I've setup both the msysgit installation directory (e.g. `C:\software\msysgit\msysgit`) on the `PATH` as well as the directory to which I extracted git-tfs (e.g. `C:\software\GitTfs-0.11.0`).

I run `msys`, and then attempt to run `git tfs` but I receive the error:

```
git: 'tfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

According to https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/wiki this should be possible.

What have I missed? Just running `git-tfs` from the command line (`cmd`) doesn't work either.

Thanks,

James

Comment: When running git-tfs by itself on the command line, I get the error 'The system cannot find the file specified' while attempting a clone, so I assume something isn't setup right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that whitespace anywhere in the PATH variable causes git to freak out and ignore all the paths after that. Adding the path to your tfs directory at the start of the PATH variable should solve it.

Examples using the bash prompt that comes with msysgit

```
PATH=$PATH:/C/software/GitTfs-0.11.0
```

did not work

```
PATH=/C/software/GitTfs-0.11.0:$PATH
```

worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi Pär, did you set this path in the current session or in a batch file? I tried exporting the `PATH` variable as you suggested (with the git tfs path coming first) but it wasn't picked up then and there - is there a command to run that re-load's msysgit's knowledge of commands on the path? I added it to set the path as the first line of `msys.bat`, and that works for me now, thanks :) Is there a specific file I should be customizing the PATH in?

Comment: It shouldn't matter when or where you set the path as long as it's done before you call git tfs. Once you've set the PATH it should be permanent and be there for all sessions until you actively remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the content of a [GitTfs-0.11.0.zip](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/downloads#uploaded_downloads), I see it contains a `git-tfs.exe`.
That means git tfs won't work, only `git-tfs`.

If you have added `C:\software\GitTfs-0.11.0` to your `PATH` (in the **[environment variables](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/06/qotw-how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/)**), this should work, provided you open a **new** DOS session, in order to inherit that new PATH.

Comment: If you read https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/wiki, then it wouldn't appear to be so?

Comment: Plus, I've already said I added it to my PATH. I tried using the command by itself (not through msysgit), but also came into a different issue, as stated in the original post.

Comment: @jamiebarrow: so in a new DOS session, you can do an `echo %PATH%` and see the right path for `git-tfs.exe`?

Comment: Yes. And in msys, I can do `env|grep GitTfs` and it also shows it on the PATH

Comment: As mentioned, I can run git-tfs (where I said "Just running `git-tfs` from the command line"), added a comment to explain what I get when attempting to clone a repository.

Comment: @jamiebarrow: ok, I didn't see the comment at first. Did you try only on a msys bash session or in a DOS session? Or both? In a DOS session, do you have HOME set? (in case it has any bearing)

Comment: @jamieborrow: even if the thread has nothing to do with git tfs, it illustrates that this kind of error could be related to a .Net4 installation issue: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaResourceEditor.aspx?msg=3559812

Comment: @VonC I don't see how that post is related at all, and don't have time to read through it all... have you used msysgit or git-tfs...?

Comment: @jamiebarrow: it was only to mention that the GitHub page of git-tfs mentions "You need .NET 4 and either the 2008 or 2010 version of Team Explorer installed". It is possible that your error message comes from one of those prerequisites missing or not in the PATH somehow. I haven't used git tfs directly, I know msysgit well (http://superuser.com/search?q=user:141+[msysgit] or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:6309+[msysgit]

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your help, but no, nothing to do with .NET or TFS related setup. Pär found that the ordering of the PATH could be the issue (perhaps part of the PATH is invalid and doesn't get processed by msysgit), so I used the path to git-tfs as the first item [ well, close to first :) ]

Answer (score -1):

The steps below worked for me:

1. Download GitTfs zip and unblock downloaded files (right click each file->properties->click unblock
2. Copy files to Git folder (for me C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin) (I've 15 files)
3. Now the `git tfs` command should work.

Comment: That will probably work. But doesn't allow me to have a custom path to where I install my different utilities etc. Not useful answer.